# Developing JAX-WS web service in Tomcat that also works in web sphere

Tags: jax-ws

I've a requirement. I need to develop JAX-WS web service that is portable across Tomcat and Web Sphere. Which JAX-WS implementation I use? JAXWS-RI, Axis2 or CXF. I use Eclipse IDE. Tomcat is the development server. Web Sphere is the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Web Sphere is full application container it provides its own JAX-WS implementation. So limit yourself just to core JAX-WS elements without implementation extensions. That is why I would recommend Metro for tomcat as it is the simplest, reference implementation: https://jax-ws.java.net/

Comment: I will use Metro for Tomcat. Thanks.

Comment: Just remember to copy the metro jars to the tomcat/lib not to your webapp libs.

Comment: Any reason to copy the metro jars to the tomcat/lib? I see web service is working when copied in webapp libs. I also tried to deploy the web service in IBM Web Sphere. It worked fine.

Comment: The main reason was to prevent conflicts with WebSpehere implementation. But if it works like that you can probably leave them. Second is to reduce war size, especially if you have more than WS based webapp deployed. And the last one, it is a recommended setup for metro, due to the way how classloader loads shared and webapp libraries. If you happy leave it how it is, just when you see strange exceptions (like metthod not found in jax-ws impelemntation classes) after some update, it will be due to the mismatch of local libs and server libs.